# Why are my images in the layout load slower than texts in Android?

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I mean, that the TextViews loads almost at once, however the ImageViews loads a bit slower, and this looks very ugly, and disturbing.

What can I do against it?

I load the images of the ImageView on the fly, and set the images of the ImageViews with setImageBitmap() in a background process.

Comment: if u r downloading images from server thn it wud be bttr tht u dwnload once & keep it in cache for next time ...for the first time it will take time to download images from server . http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Drawing an image is more processor intensive than rendering text. Most likely the image has to be scaled as well. Fonts are vector based if you're setting a Bitmap, then that is definitely a raster...

Comment: That's because the system is slower loading bitmaps, you can add some kind of listener to add the text when the bitmap is loaded.

Comment: Is it OK, if I set the image in the onCreate() method of the Activity?
Is there any possibility to set the image of the ImageView in advance?

Answer (score 1):

`setImageBitmap` is time-consuming - it requires loading bitmap data from storage, memory allocation, decoding, etc, etc. A `TextView` obviously needs to do no such thing.

You can improve the situation somewhat by using placeholder images of the same size as the image that you're about to load, using transition animations, or (whenever possible) using resource drawables.

Comment: What do you mean by resource drawables?

Comment: Resource drawables are part of your application: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: Resource drawables are resources drawn using files in your res/drawable folder -- instead of a png, you can put in an "instruction" as to what the image will look like.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html